# Unable to extract the string i want from the ajax post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my asp mvc project i've got an ajax call that posts the value of a dropdown list and i want the session to be set with this value.

```
$('#dropDownMenu').on('click', 'li', function () {
        var txt = $('#schoolButtons').text();
        data = {session: txt};
        var requestValue = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SetSession")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: "requestValue="+requestValue ,        
        }).success(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        });
    });


   public ActionResult SetSession(string requestValue)
   {
            var sessionVal = Convert.ToString(requestValue);
            if (sessionVal==null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("session is null");
            }

            Session["key"] = sessionVal;
            return Json(requestValue);
   }
```

When I output the value of the session i'm getting the string {"session":"State School"} when all i want is "State School". I know in the function data is set to {session: txt} but how do i just extract that txt?

Regards,

Mike.

Comment: Its just `$.ajax({ ..... data: { requestValue: txt }, .... })` (and why in the world do you have `Convert.ToString()` - its already a `string`!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the JSON value you need to read it this way

```
var requestValue = data.session
```

Since you pass it as a string into the function and want to read it in the function, this is what I sugggest you do. You need to convert the string to JSON and extract the value.

```
public ActionResult SetSession(string requestValue)
   {
    var JSONData = JSON.parse(requestValue);
    var sessionVal = JSONData.session;
...
...
```

Comment: Sorry Sharjeel. I'm a bit confused. In the controller requestValue is passed into SetSession. That requestValue is a string that equals "session":"State School". But I just want to extract the value "State School" which is my problem. I'm not worried about the return value.